Powershell query to Azure app insights looking for exceptions
$query = @{
    "timespan"="P7D"
    "Query" = "exceptions"
} | ConvertTo-Json

$component = Get-AzApplicationInsights -ResourceGroupName $appInsResourceGroupName -Name $appInsName
$apiKey = '***************'
$Details = (Invoke-WebRequest -Method POST -Uri https://api.applicationinsights.io/v1/apps/$($component.AppId)/query -ContentType application/json -Body $query -Headers @{"X-Api-Key"=$apiKey}).Content

The above code returns basically an empty table.

If I login to the portal using the same account that I'm running the PS script under I return data.

I have my resource group and app insights name variables set to the correct names (at least I've checked them 3 or 4 times and they LOOK correct) My apikey is created and has "read telemetry" access.
Why is my powershell script not returning the data like it should?  Been scratching my brain for 2 days on this.
Any help is appreciated!

Try with a GET request: Invoke-WebRequest -Method GET -Uri "https://api.applicationinsights.io/v1/apps/$($component.AppId)/query?query=exceptions&timespan=P7D" -ContentType application/json -Headers @{"X-Api-Key"=$apiKey}

as Mathias stated, the correct call is GET https://api.applicationinsights.io/v1/apps/{appId}/query?query={query}&timespan={timespan}

Thank you for the response.  I changed it to a get using your posted command and I get the same results.  I get a successful response just like I do with the POST command and the "Content" parameter is still empty:
StatusCode        : 200
StatusDescription : OK
Content           : {"tables":[]}
.....

$details.content
{"tables":[]}

